# Why a zero too close to the imaginary axis gives bad berformances?

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering, control-theory, systems-engineering

I am studying control systems, and I have found that if I consider I control scheme where I filter the reference , if the zero of the pre-filter is too close to the imaginary axis, we have a degradation of the performances. For example, I have plotted this in Matlab:

[image]

in which I moved towards the imaginary axis by increasing a constant value tau_num. The closest zero to the imaginary axis is relative to tau_num = 0.7, which infact has the worst performances, since it is present a resonance peack.

Thus, so far I have demonstarted this to be true just with Matlab, but I don't understand the reason for which this happens. I have found just that it is present a limit from the physical components, for which the zero cannot be too close to the dominant pole, but I haven't found anything else.

Can somebody please help me? Thanks in advance.

[EDIT] I am working with the following scheme:

[image]

in which I have a prefilter $C_r(s)$, and the transfer functions I am using are the following:

```
P = 1/[(1+s)*(1+0.05*s)^2];
C = 10*(s+1)/s;
```

and for the pre-filter I am considering different values, which are shown in the plot above, which are:

```
tau_d1 = 0.9;
tau_num1 = 0.1;

tau_d2 = 0.9;
tau_num2 = 0.4;

tau_d3 = 0.9;
tau_num3 = 0.7;

C_r_1 = (1+tau_num1*s)/(1+tau_d1*s);
C_r_2 = (1+tau_num2*s)/(1+tau_d2*s);
C_r_3 = (1+tau_num3*s)/(1+tau_d3*s);
```

and the closed loop transfer functions are:

```
T1 =  C_r_1*C*P/(1+C*P);
T2 =  C_r_2*C*P/(1+C*P);
T3 =  C_r_3*C*P/(1+C*P);
```

which I plot in this way:

```
figure;
bodemag(T1,'b',T2,'r',T3,'g'),grid
legend('tau_num = 0.1','tau_num = 0.4','tau_num = 0.7');
title('amplitude of frequency response as zero gets slower')
```

Comment: Please show the transfer function that you're working with.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have edited my question.

Comment: Try plotting $Y(s)/M_r(s)$ and $M_r(s)/R(s)$ separately -- I think that $Y(s)/M_r(s)$ is pretty well behaved, and you're messing it up with the pre-compensator.

Comment: It is true that when the amplitude of the equal ripple Chebychev filters increases when their zeros get closer to the imaginary vertical axis.which usually corresponds to higher Q poles